# Meteor 1.6.1 and Vue 2 integration

Tags: meteor, vuejs2

For two days I'm trying to start using Vue 2 in my Meteor project. First I looked up some packages, and found https://github.com/meteor-vue/vue-meteor, but other than a list of packages it lacks anything usable itself, so here is that. A separate search on Atmosphere yielded in something I could actually use, namely https://atmospherejs.com/akryum/vue, but despite following every instruction I could find for this package, I don't think it works correctly for me, for example, I don't get the console messages regarding component hot reload, only the usual standard Meteor startup messages+messages when a file changes. It doesn't make use of the `client/main.html` file, unless I import it explicitly in `client/main.js`, but then I get a runtime error about missing module `./main.html`, even tho I can clearly see then the template rendered, but w/o Vue magic in it. In the provided example project (without Blaze) I don't see the HTML being imported explicitly anywhere, so something is definitely off here. There are no other hints and clues in any produced output. So I'm stuck in limbo.

P. S. I also just realized it doesn't even do anything with the `.vue` components, as 1) I forgot to change an import from `.js` to `.vue`, and the app didn't crash at any time, and then, the imported `.vue` file was actually syntactically incorrect, until I fixed it just now.

Comment: Even I faced same issue. I love vue js. But you can start using react js as it has huge community supporting and react js is getting grip. Vue js with meteor might have many developers out there but still lacks support on Stackoverflow. If you want to start learning react js with meteor, it is very easy and you can follow Levelup tutorials on YouTube.

Comment: if your still in the market for a boilerplate - found this the other day :
"A minimalist boilerplate for products with Vue + Meteor."
GitHub - alexandesigner/lets:
There is a lot of 'candy-floss' - Stylus and like - but beside that it's an excellent start

Answer (score 2):

For a starter boilerplate of Meteor + Vue, the perfect bundling + packages selection is Akryum's https://github.com/meteor-vue/vue-meteor-demo

I used it, and deployed to galaxy without problems. Excellent start.

This boilerplate contains: 
Meteor 1.4 - 1.7+ + tracker +  Vuejs 2 + vue-router + vuex (store) + graphql set up.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I am starting to document my experience while trying to integrate the 2 technologies. If you want to see more: https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-vue-in-2018/44246

I have a bit different folder structure, but hopefully it is still relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I have written an article that describes in detail the steps to install Vue and Vue Router in a Meteor application. I don't like putting links on Stackoverflow, but it's too much detail included in a answer here.

https://medium.com/@simonjcarr/adding-vue-and-vue-router-to-meteor-7c411131494f

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following setup.

Packages

> .meteor/packages

```
meteor-base@1.3.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have mobile-
experience@1.0.5              # Packages for a great mobile UX 
mongo@1.4.2                   # The database Meteor supports right now  
tracker@1.1.3                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-js@2.3.1    # JS minifier run for production mode 
es5-shim@4.7.0                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers 
ecmascript@0.10.6             # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

shell-server@0.3.1            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command

static-html akryum:vue-component 
akryum:vue-blaze-template 
session@1.1.7 
check 
dynamic-import@0.3.0 
fourseven:scss 
seba:minifiers-autoprefixer
```

> package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.44",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0",
    "@deveodk/vue-toastr": "^1.0.4",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.2.6",
    "vue-router": "^2.5.1",
    "vuex": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Client directory

> client/main.html

```
<body class="pace-done md-skin">
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

> client/main.scss

```
// Libs
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor'
import Vue from 'vue'
import { router } from '/imports/client/plugins/router';
import store from '/imports/vuex/store'
import AppLayout from '/imports/client/ui/AppLayout.vue'

// import '/imports/client/plugins/plugin_name'

// App start
Meteor.startup(() => {
    new Vue({
        store,
        router,
        el: '#app',
        render: h => h(AppLayout)
    })
});
```

Rest is standard vue. I can add alse `AppLayout.vue` to demonstrate what I mean

> /imports/client/ui/AppLayout.vue

```
<template>

  <router-view></router-view>

</template>

<script>
  export default {
      name: 'AppLayout'
  }
</script>
```